# Stop firing ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

The issue is best explained by the code:

```
var myinterval = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        data: data
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) { /* I want to clear current interval */ }
            else { /* let it firing ajax requests further */ }
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

So, what I want is to fire ajax requests each second to check if status of "something" changed. And if this something has changed properly, I want to stop checking on it. Basically, I'm asking how do I do it the best and most understood way.

What I did before is kind of ugly:

```
window.x = {
  'debug' : document.location.host.indexOf('.ru') != document.location.host.length - 3
  };
var setItem = function(i,v) {
  if (window.x['debug'] && typeof window.x[i] != 'undefined' && typeof console != 'undefined' && window.x[i] != v)
    console.log('Value of item ' + i + ' has changed from ' + window.x[i] + ' to ' + v)
  window.x[i] = v
};
var getItem = function(i) {
  if (window.x['debug'] && typeof window.x[i] == 'undefined' && typeof console != 'undefined')
    console.warn('Value of item ' + i + ' is undefined (maybe was not set?)')
  return window.x[i]
};
```

So, yea, I've occupied global `x` here (this is my temporary storage). Now I can set my interval `var` to `x`:

```
setItem('myinterval', myinterval);
```

inside success function I can get this interval:

```
getIntem('myinterval');
```

and stop it:

```
clearInterval(getItem('myinterval'));
```

But this is really ugly, isn't it? 
What is <s>the best</s> better way of doing that?

Comment: set `var x = $.ajax(...';` and then x.abort() when you require it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `clearInterval(myinterval)`:

```
var myinterval = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        data: data
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                clearInterval(myinterval);
            }
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already saving a reference to the interval in `myinterval`, so what's wrong with:

```
clearInterval(myinterval);
```